# List of rows with all the possible combinations of answers from a questionnaire

Tags: python, excel, list, combinations, data-analysis

I need to create a list of rows with all the possible combinations of answers from a questionnaire. I'm using Jupyter Notebook with Python code.

There are around 40 questions and some of them have only 3 answer options to choose from, and some around ten. Some of them are text strings, and some are positive natural numbers.

That's how a part of the questionnaire looks like:

[image]

The outcome that I would like to have in an Excel sheet would be a list of rows with different combinations of answers in separate cells (I imagine the list of rows will be very long considering so many variables - not even sure if this is possible to store in one Excel sheet). I need to have all possible combinations of answers.

[image]

I tried this code but it shows me memory error.

```
import pandas as pd

from itertools import product

df = pd.read_excel("Test2023 PYTHON.xlsx")

uniques = [df[i].unique().tolist() for i in df.columns]

combinations = pd.DataFrame(product(*uniques), columns = df.columns)

combinations_df.to_excel("combinations.xlsx", index=False)
```

As a next step, I would like to narrow down the rows by adding conditions, e.g. if Question 0 is answered as "No" or "N/A" then Question 1 and 2 have to be answered 0. There would be more conditions like this for other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies up front this isn't a direct answer in Python but hopefully gives some direction.

I've actually been working basically this same problem but in JS, but the math is the same regardless of language.  Basically you are looking at all possible combinations which means multiplying the number of options for each column to find the total number of possible combinations.

Say we have an a list/array of objects/dicts like this:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    name: 'Question 0',
    answers: ['Yes', 'No']
  },
  {
    name: 'Question 1',
    answers: ['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C']
  },
  {
    name: 'Question 2',
    answers: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  },
  {
    name: 'Question 3',
    answers: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  }
]

console.log('All columns')
console.log(columns)

let allPossibleAnswers = []

columns[0].answers.forEach(column0 => columns[1].answers.forEach(column1 => columns[2].answers.forEach(column2=>columns[3].answers.forEach(column3=>{
  const curSetOfAnswers = [column0,column1,column2,column3]
  allPossibleAnswers.push(curSetOfAnswers)
  console.log(curSetOfAnswers.join(', '))
}))))

console.log('Total count:', allPossibleAnswers.length)
function renderCells(setOfAnswers) {
  return setOfAnswers.map(answer=>`<td>${answer}</td>`)
}
function renderTable() {
  return allPossibleAnswers.map(setOfAnswers => `<tr>${renderCells(setOfAnswers)}</tr>`)
}
document.body.innerHTML=`<table>${renderTable()}</table>`

document.body.innerHTML += `Total Count ${allPossibleAnswers.length}`
```

Can see from running the snippet with just these 4 questions and answer sets we end up with 600 rows of data (in general this shouldn't be a problem but can see how this grows rapidly).

2 * 3 * 10 * 10 = 600

Say you have 40 questions and on average they have 5 answers each then looking at roughly:

5^40 = 9,094,947,017,729,282,379,150,390,625 answer combinations, if each answer option can be stored in say 4 bytes this is 36,379,788,070,917,129,516,601,562,500 so yah running out of RAM with this kind of data set is definitely a possibility :D If you add the conditions that reduce the number of options it will help but can try doing the math to see if will fall anywhere within reason too.